# How to remove tabs from blank lines using sed?

Tags: tabs, sed, code-formatting, blank-line

I'd like to use **sed** to remove tabs from otherwise blank lines.  For example a line containing only `\t\n` should change to `\n`.  **What's the syntax for this?**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`sed` does not know about escape sequences like `\t`. So you will have to literally type a `tab` on your console:

```
sed 's/^    *$//g' <filename>
```

If you are on bash, then you can't type `tab` on the console. You will have to do `^V` and then press `tab`. (`Ctrl-V` and then `tab`) to print a literal tab.

Comment: If using bash, you could also do `sed $'s/^\t*$//g'`, because using a dollar-sign on a single-quoted string formats escape codes such as \t.

Answer (score 1):

The other posted solution will work when there is 1 (and only 1) tab in the line.  Note that Raze2dust points out that sed requires you to type a literal tab.  An alternative is:

```
sed '/[^      ]/!s/   //g' file-name.txt
```

Which substitues away tabs from lines that only have tabs.  The inverted class matches lines that contain anything bug a tab - the following '!' causes it to not match those lines - meaning only lines that have only tabs.  The substitution then only runs on those lines, removing all tabs.

Answer (score 1):

To replace arbitrary whitespace lines with an empty line, use

```
sed -r 's/^\s+$//'
```

The -r flag says to use extended regular expressions, and the ^\s+$ pattern matches all lines with some whitespace but no other characters.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:

```
sed -r '/^\s+$/d' my_file.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

I've noticed \t is not recognized by UNIX. Being said, use the actual  key. In the code below, TAB represents pressing the tab key.

$ sed 's/TAB//g' oldfile > newfile

Friendly tip: to ensure you have tabs in the file you are trying to remove tabs from use the following code to see if \t appears

$ od -c filename

Answer (score -2):

```
grep -o ".*" file > a; mv a file;
```

Comment: And this does what, exactly? Because it doesn't do what the OP asked.